# Return specific data from API when ENTER is pressed

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to return a specific data when Enter key is pressed. It's something like a barcodes scanner. After each scann scanner enter key code(keyCode = 13) and then app should go through each json object and return the whole json object depends on the scanned barcode.
At this momment I can get whole json... So as I don't need whole json I would like at first to get blank form and after I put barcode in the input field and press ENTER it sould return the sepcific object...
Yeah kind of a complicated task.

**index.vue:**

```
       <template>
      <div class="row">
                <div class="card mx-auto">
                   <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card w-auto mx-auto">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h3>{{ id }}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                     <form >
                                <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col">
                                         <input
                      type="number"
                      v-model="barcodeSearch"
                      name="barcode"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="inlineFormInput"
                      placeholder="Barkodas..."
                    />
                                            placeholder="Barkodas...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                    <table class="table">      
                        <tbody v-if="items">
                            <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.PrekesID" class="tItems">
                                <tr >{{ item.Prekes_Pavad}}</tr>
                                <hr>
                                <tr >{{ item.Prekes_Kodas}}</tr>
                                <hr>
                                <tr >{{ item.PrekesID}}</tr>
                                
                                
                                <hr>
                                <div class="col">
                                        <input type="number" name="ItemsFound" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInput"
                                            placeholder="Faktinis likutis">
                                    </div>
                                 <hr>
                                  <div class="col">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Patvirtinti</button>
                                    </div>   
                            </div>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
      </div>        
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        props: ['id'],
       data() {
        return {
          items: []
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        fetch("https:**internal address which return json. Example below.**)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => (this.items = data))
          .catch((err) => console.log("err.message"));
      },
    },
 computed: {
    searchedBarcode() {
      const value = this.barcodeSearch;
      let reactiveArray = this.items.filter(function (item) {
        if (item && item.Barkodas) {
          return item.Barkodas.indexOf(value) > -1;
        }
        return false;
      });

      if (reactiveArray.length > 0) {
        return reactiveArray;
      } else {
        return this.items;
      }
    },
  },
    </script>
```

**Json exmple:**

```
[
    {
        "EilesNumeris": 1,
        "EilutesNumeris": 1,
        "PrekesID": 521328,
        "Prekes_Kodas": "5METP000000084",
        "Barkodas": "000000220136",
        "Prekes_Pavad": "M6-Zn POVERŽLĖ DIN9021",
    },
    {
        "EilesNumeris": 1,
        "EilutesNumeris": 2,
        "PrekesID": 68316,
        "Prekes_Kodas": "5MST000057",
        "Barkodas": "0000010008812",
        "Prekes_Pavad": "MEDSRAIGČIAI BLT 6,0x40 grūd.D 1/200",
    },
    {
        "EilesNumeris": 1,
        "EilutesNumeris": 3,
        "PrekesID": 314849,
        "Prekes_Kodas": "5MSGR00023",
        "Barkodas": "000003962",
        "Prekes_Pavad": "%-4,2x19 SAVISRIEGIS Į MET. BE GRĄŽTELIO (AKCIJA)",
    },
```

Comment: Sure you can loop over the array of objects (`this.items`). Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I was trying this...:
 <input type="number" v-model="barcodeSearch" name="barcode" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInput"
                                        placeholder="Barkodas...">
 computed:{
      searchedBarcode(){
          const value = this.barcodeSearch;
          let reactiveArray = this.items.filter(function(item){
              return item.Barkodas.indexOf(value) > -1
          })
          if (reactiveArray.length > 0){
              return reactiveArray
          }
          else{
              return this.items
          }
      }

  }

Comment: Please put it in the question, it's hard to read in a comment. Also others won't read through all the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: Ok good. Is this really your code or copy&pasted together? The `computed()` function must be at the same level as `mounted()` and the indentation is inconsistent. So when you debug the filtering function does the filtered array look correct? Do you get errors on the browser console?

Comment: Yeahs it's copied and changed a little.  The filter function is working well but the thing is it filters on every changed char and I would like to filter only when Enter is pressed. I tried to make input V-on:keyup.enter = "barcodeSearch" but I get errors thats barcodeSearch is not a function.

Comment: Okay sure. I've come up with something. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a form submit handler

As we discussed in the comments: Yes, you cannot call `barcodeSearch` as a method, it is a computed value. But why not create a form handler for the component?

Let's add a form submit handler. You only change `this.barcodeSearch` in that submit method and don't bind it to the input. This way the only time `barcodeSearch` is updated is when the form is submitted (pressing enter, clicking search button, clicking "OK" on mobile, etc.).

So remove `v-bind="barcodeSearch"` from your form first.

Add a submit method for the form:

```js
methods: {
  submitForm() {
    this.barcodeSearch = this.$refs.searchForm.barcode;
  }
}
```

Then add a `submit` handler to the form:

```
...
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm" ref="searchForm">
...
```

Now the computed value will only change when submitting the form.